# I use networkx.add_edge(),but nothing of edges added? why?

Tags: python, networkx, edges

`import networkx as net`

```
def get_Children(g, df):
    for i in range(0, (df.iloc[:,0].size)-1):
        f1 = df.iloc[i]['firm1']
        f2 = df.iloc[i]['firm2']
        if f1 != f2:     
            if df.iloc[i]['children'] == 1.0:
                g.add_edge(f1, f2)
            else: continue
    return g
g = net.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(index)
get_Children(g, df)
```

data like this:

firm1 firm2 children

- firm1 firm2 children
- 1     2       0
- 1     3       1
- 1     4       0
- 2     3       1
- 2     1       0
- 2     4       1
- 3     1       0
- 3     2       0
- 3     4       0
- 4     1       0
- 4     2       0
- 4     3       0

if firm1 is the children of firm2 then get 1 otherwise 0.

but i use the function above add nothing of edges.

In [177]: g.edges()

Out[177]: EdgeView([])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your code here and I seem to have been able to produce edges with `add_edge()` using mostly the code you provided:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx 

df = pd.DataFrame({'firm1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 
                   'firm2':[2,3,4,3,1,4,1,2,4,1,2,3], 
                   'children':[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

This gives the DataFrame you provided:

```
    children    firm1   firm2
0   0   1   2
1   1   1   3
2   0   1   4
3   1   2   3
4   0   2   1
5   1   2   4
6   0   3   1
7   0   3   2
8   0   3   4
9   0   4   1
10  0   4   2
11  0   4   3
```

I replicated the rest of your code, and the only thing I changed was replacing `index` with `[1,2,3,4]` (and also `net` with `nx`, the convention for the NetworkX package:

```
def get_Children(g, df):
    for i in range(0, (df.iloc[:,0].size)-1):
        f1 = df.iloc[i]['firm1']
        f2 = df.iloc[i]['firm2']
        if f1 != f2:     
            if df.iloc[i]['children'] == 1.0:
                g.add_edge(f1, f2)
            else: continue
    return g

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4])
get_Children(g, df)
g.edges()
```

The `g.edges()` results in:

```
EdgeView([(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)])
```

I'm using Python 3 to reproduce this. Perhaps you were using an incorrect value for `index`?

Comment: thank U @briancaffey I think i am wrong in using iloc for DataFrame, the normal method is f1 = df.iloc[i, 0]  f2 = df.iloc[i, 1]